# object module is not callable , invalid syntax on constant

Tags: python, oop

I am new to python. I got `Syntax Error: invalid syntax & object module is not callable`

Thanks for your help

Spot.py

```
class Spot(object):
    isBunny = bool()
    UP = 0
    SLEEP = 2

    def __init__(self, newIsBunny):
        self.isBunny = newIsBunny
        self.nextCycle = self.UP
```

Test.py

```
import Spot
i=2
if i==Spot.SLEEP
    a=Spot(True)
print a.isBunny
```

Comment: Please give the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Borgleader says, instead of

```
import Spot
```

use

```
from Spot import Spot
```

This should fix the "module is not callable" error.

When you say

```
import Spot
```

then "Spot" is the whole module.  Spot.Spot is the Spot class inside the Spot module, which is what you really want.  Using the `from Spot import Spot` syntax lets you pull in just the Spot class from the Spot module, and call it Spot.

Answer (score 2):

For one the code in your class should be indented. That is how python knows that the code is part of the class (the same way indentation tells python which code is part of a function, or a loop).

Secondly you're misssing a `:` after `if i==Spot.SLEEP`